# Delphi - Checking MySQL Server status from registry

Tags: mysql, delphi, registry, dbexpress

I know how to check the status of MySQL server in Delphi when the server is run as a process (I am using dbexpress as a database tool). However, I don't know how to check the status of the server as a service (from Registry-Services-MySQL55- version 5.5).

I tried something like this:

```
...
uses Registry;
...
Registry. ... Services. ... .MySQL55.Running:=true;
```

but that doesn't work.

Could someone show the proper way of calling the Registry in Delphi and resolving this problem?

Comment: What does reading the Registry have to do with determining a server's running status? Please clarify your goal.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau, I want to read the Registry and see if the service, MySQL55 is running or not.
If it is running, the label in delphi form should indicate e.g. "State: Running", and if not, "State: Stopped". This should happen on
run-time, and no additional prompt forms are needed.

How to achieve this?

Comment: The registry holds whether it starts disabled, manual, automatic, deferred etc. I dont believe it holds if its running or not

Comment: The registry does not contain the current running state. It only contains information about how it starts or whether it is disabled. You're barking up the wrong tree here.

Comment: The correct way to query an installed service's running status is with [`QueryServiceStatus()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684939.aspx)